# Azure pipelines: error MSB4019 WebApplication.targets was not found

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I created an episerver alloy project, which builds and runs fine in visual studio after setting up some nuget packages, and I can deploy to azure and run in azure from VS without issue.

I am now trying to get the build to work in pipelines.

Following the instructions, I added a "nuget restore" task, and pointed it at a NuGet.config.
This works.

Then it gets to the build stage, and gives:

D:\a\1\s\DxcAlloy.csproj(335,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I have no idea how to debug this.  Some posts say that error can happen if you dont have visual studio installed, but I cant install visual studio on azure pipelines...

I removed the existing ".net restore" task, as it failed, and am guessing that just my nuget restore is all I need - this is a guess.

The pipeline "agent specification" is vs2017-win16

The project was created in VS 2019.

In desperation, I added a "Use .NET core" task, and set the version to the one which build is complaining is missing, i.e. 3.1.202.

This didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you build your project using `dotnet build` task. Below configuration in your .csproj file will be evaluated to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` (What you see from the error)

`<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0</VSToolsPath>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />`

Microsoft.WebApplication.targets usually exists in below location. That is why it errors out `...Microsoft.WebApplication.targets not found`.

> In Visual Studio 2017 `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"`
>
> In Visual Studio 2019 `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"`

The workaround for above issue is using [Msbuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) task or [Visual Studio build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) task to build your projects. See below example:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '**/*.csproj'
    enabled: true
```

For your case, you also need to set **agent specification** to agent `windows-latest`. For visual studio 2019(`v16.0`) is only installed in agent `windows-latest`.

If you have to run your pipeline on agent "vs2017-win16" (only visual studio 2017(`v15.0`) is installed). You need to change the `VSToolsPath` in the .csproj file to `<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0</VSToolsPath>`

If you have to use `dotnet build` to build your projects. You can hard code the import path in csproj file as workaround.

`<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />`

Comment: Neither MSBuild nor Visual Studio Build tasks are helping in my case...could you check my post here if you have a chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246997/why-is-the-project-file-not-found-even-though-i-am-using-an-msbuild-task